# Animated series from the early 2000s about teens saving dinosaurs?

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember this animated series from the early 2000s intended for young audiences. It is about a group of teenagers who are trying to save dinosaurs, or maybe turn into dinosaurs? Regardless, the kids face off against a man with black hair that has a white streak in it. One thing that I distinctly remember is that both sides are in search of a substance called "primordial ooze." The animation style reminded me of *Godzilla: The Series*, the spinoff of the 1998 Roland Emmerich film. Does anyone remember this series, and on a lesser note, was it any good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is '[Dino Squad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DinoSquad)', broadcast in 2007.

> Five teenagers, Rodger, Max, Caruso, Fiona and Buzz, gain the power to turn into dinosaurs by getting covered in Victor Veloci's primordial ooze that mutated their DNA on a school field trip to the tide pools when they were rescuing Rump. With the help of their mysterious science teacher, Ms. Moynihan (who is an anthropomorphic Velociraptor), they learn to use their unique abilities to protect the planet from Victor Veloci. Victor is widely known as the head of company Raptor Dyne, but is also a 65-million-year-old anthropomorphic Velociraptor. His secret identity is unknown to everyone except himself and the audience. His true plan is to turn everyone into dinosaurs by using primordial ooze and increase the climate to that of the Mesozoic era with the goal of returning the world to how it was when dinosaurs ruled and tries capturing them in their dinosaur forms, not knowing they are humans. However, his plans always backfired and thus the return to the age of the dinosaurs was not meant to be. Dino Squad is set in Kittery Point, Maine.